# How can I set, rather than fit, the co-efficients of a spline interpolation using scipy?

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy

I am trying to train a predictive model and want to use a spline-like interpolation to represent some function that forms part of the model. However, this is not a simple case of fitting some x,y data over a region to find the spline co-efficients, rather the function being approximated by the spline forms part of a non-linear generative model. To find the co-efficients I need to use non-linear minimisation algorithms to optimise against a training data set. This means I need to be able to directly specify a set of co-efficients rather than using the fitting methods in scipy.interpolate (such as scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline).

Is there a way to specify spline co-efficients and then use the resulting object as a function within the model? If this isn't possible with scipy, is there another python library that supports this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you basically want to specify your own spline coefficients as independent parameters and then evaluate them using the built-in spline functionality.

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html

splev takes knots and coefficients typically generated by splrep or splprep, but you should be able to bypass those routines and modify the coefficients yourself.

Comment: Yes, you've understood what I'm trying to do (and stated it more clearly than I managed). The only thing I can't follow is that splrep and splprep allow you to specify periodic boundary conditions, but splev does not? Is there a different (but related) routine to splev for use with periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: I think if you tell splrep to assume a periodic function, then you could use those coefficients in splev and have the periodicity, but you may have to shift your independent variable to be on the range [ x[0] x[n] ]